# Aggregate dataframe in R to get mean of groups based on "detect flag"

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, summarize

I have the data frame:

```
    structure(list(Loc_name = c("U3R", "U3R", "U3R", "U3R", "U3R", 
"U3R", "HWY301", "HWY301", "HWY301", "HWY301", "HWY301", "HWY301", 
"U3R", "U3R", "U3R", "U3R", "U3R", "U3R", "HWY301", "HWY301", 
"HWY301", "HWY301", "HWY301", "HWY301"), `fish type` = c("bass", 
"bass", "bass", "catfish", "catfish", "catfish", "flathead", 
"flathead", "flathead", "bass", "bass", "bass", "bass", "bass", 
"bass", "catfish", "catfish", "catfish", "flathead", "flathead", 
"flathead", "bass", "bass", "bass"), Report_result_value = c(1.1, 
1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 1.1, 1.2, 
1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3), Chemical_Name = c("Cs-137", 
"Cs-137", "Cs-137", "Cs-137", "Cs-137", "Cs-137", "Cs-137", "Cs-137", 
"Cs-137", "Cs-137", "Cs-137", "Cs-137", "SR-90", "SR-90", "SR-90", 
"SR-90", "SR-90", "SR-90", "SR-90", "SR-90", "SR-90", "SR-90", 
"SR-90", "SR-90"), detect_flag = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "Y", "N", "N")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

I would like to get the average report result value of a particular chemical, in a particular fish, at a particular location. The rules for taking the average are:  if the detect flag is "N" for a particular fish type, at a particular location, for a particular chemical name, then the mean is zero.  Otherwise, the mean is the straight average, regardless of detect flag.  For example, the average of SR-90 for fish "Flathead" at HWY301 would be 0.  Conversely, the average of Cs-137 for fish "bass" at HWY301 would be 4.2.

I've heard Loops are slow in R, so I'm trying to avoid using a loop as much as possible.  Does anyone have an approach in R for calculating the mean considering the rules for averaging above?  Much appreciated.

I have tried aggregate and dplyr's summarize function but I have not been able to accommodate the averaging rule with those approaches.  I'm fairly new to R.

Comment: So is the rule that there has to be at least one `detect_flag = 'Y'` for the average to be calculated normally, otherwise it's 0?

Comment: We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(fish_type)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: @thelatemail  Yes that is correct.

Comment: Just to be clear: do you mean that if **all** of the detect flags for the group location/fish/chemical = "N" then the mean = 0, but if **any** of the flags for the group location/fish/chemical = "Y" then calculate the mean?

Comment: @neilfws, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments "there has to be at least one detect_flag = 'Y' for the average to be calculated normally, otherwise it's 0":

```
fish_data %>% 
  group_by(Loc_name, `fish type`, Chemical_Name) %>% 
  summarise(meanVal = ifelse("Y" %in% detect_flag, 
                             mean(Report_result_value), 
                             0)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  Loc_name `fish type` Chemical_Name meanVal
  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>           <dbl>
1 HWY301   bass        Cs-137            4.2
2 HWY301   bass        SR-90             4.2
3 HWY301   flathead    Cs-137            0  
4 HWY301   flathead    SR-90             0  
5 U3R      bass        Cs-137            1.2
6 U3R      bass        SR-90             1.2
7 U3R      catfish     Cs-137            2.2
8 U3R      catfish     SR-90             2.2
```